# RealmSwift - librealm-ios.a takes up much space

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, git, realm

I have just started to look out in Realm, in Swift. Very simple and practical to use. I had a problem with the first push through Git I received, from SourceTree, a notice that said "The file librealm-ios.a have big dimension" (50MB). 
Excuse my ignorance ( and my English ), but this library file will be integrated in the creation of the .ipa file? or it serves only during development? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

according to [this topic](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/2581) it will cost 23 mb in ipa size.But you should consider app thinning, Apple will properly optimize your build and send smaller chunks ( 1MB) to user.

Comment: In practice under development it weighs about 50 MB, the creation of the .ipa file weighs 23MB and finally Apple reduces all at 1MB into the store? (Thanks for the answer)

Comment: in store still bigger size but users only download necessary parts of application.App thinning is Apple response of partial downloading it will reduce size needs of applications in smaller device sets.

Comment: Ah ok , right! . In practice my .ipa will have a size of about 20MB but then the actual size of the app downloaded from users will be decided by Apple in base of your rules.

Comment: app thinning or bitcode here more details.It's kinda boring but worth to read :) https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AppThinning/AppThinning.html